# R packages installed in RStudio not found in Pycharm

Tags: python, r, pycharm, package

I am writing a script that calls `R functions` defined in `R scripts` from a `python project`. I am using `Pycharm` for my project as an IDE. I followed the steps [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/r-plugin-support.html) for using the `R plugin` in `Pycharm`. I have downloaded many R packages in `RStudio` before using R through Pycharm. However, I am un-able to find all the R packages previously installed in the system in the `R packages` in `PyCharm`. What should I do ?

When I try to load them from the terminal of pycharm I get the following:

```
> library(performanceEstimation)
Error in library(performanceEstimation) :
  there is no package called 'performanceEstimation'
>
```

Comment: If you run `.libPaths()` and `R.home()` in Pycham and Rstudio do you get different paths? Perhaps Pycharm is set up to use a different R version installed at a different location than your Rstudio

Comment: @MrFlick They give the same output in both ```RStudio``` and ```PyCharm```

Comment: So when you say you are unable to find all the previous installed packages, what does that mean exactly? Do you get an error message when you try to load them or something? What exactly doesn't work right now?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes exactly, I get an error when I try to load them + Pycharm has a place called ```R packages``` which display the R packages installed for the project, also they are not found there!!!

Comment: What's the error you get? You say the `.libPaths()` are exactly the same? What does `installed.packages()` show in each?

Comment: Wait, you are calling `install.packages`? I thought the packages were already installed. Did you mean to run `library(e1071)` instead?

Comment: @MrFlick yes I am calling ```install.packeges()``` because the libraries (that are previously installed in the system through RStudio) are not integrated in my PyCharm project, so I cannot even do ```load(library)```